# Why JS returns NaN in: ` + 'any_string'`

Tags: javascript, nan

**Why JS returns NaN in: `+ 'any_string'`?**

Please check the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "+" tries to convert the string to an integer.
See docs [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7)

As it has **failed** to convert it to a number, the output is [NaN : Not A Number](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

```js
console.log(+"3");
console.log(+"randomString");
```

Comment: thx for a link to doc

Answer (score 3):

Using the unary plus operator you can convert something into a number. By doing `+'some_string'` you convert the string to a number, but since `some_string` is not a valid number you get `NaN` Not a Number.